# SystemVerilog - go over all the child member from the parent class

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have the following base class:

```
class base_transaction extends uvm_sequence_item();

   bit [] rand_bit_list;


   function int my_randomize(int seed);
   ....
   endfunction: my_randomize()

endclass: base_transaction
```

There are several classes which extends the base_transaction class.

Is there any systemVrilog/UVM  option to go over all the child member (one of the extended classes) from the my_randomize() function of the base_transaction class?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Are you saying that there exists many objects of class _child_class_ and you wist to randomise them all by a single call to `my_randomize`?

Comment: @Matthew Taylor -  yes.

Comment: I think you will have to implement this yourself. Perhaps you could implement a static member that is a queue of the class itself and then push each reference onto that queue each time you call `new`. Perhaps you could then have a static function that iterates over the queue and calls the `my_randomize` method in each? I suspect there is probably a _design pattern_ that does this. You might want to ask this question with a _design pattern_ tag. (If you're feeling brave. You know what Stack Overflow is like. You'll probably commit some faux pas and get shot down in flames.)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not any option in Systemveilog/UVM to do what your want. But we can do something like that with the following code.

```
// Add this queue in parent class - base_transaction
static base_transaction child_list[$];

// Add this function in parent class - base_transaction
function register_child (base_transaction child);
  base_transaction::child_list.push_back (child);
endfunction

// Your extended class
class new_transaction extends base_transaction;
  function new ();
    super.register_child (this);
  endfunction

  // Other stuff related to your new class
endclass
```

So now you can access all of your child members with `base_transaction::child_list` queue.